# R: Calculating overlap polygon area

Tags: r, polygon, spatial

I am having some difficulties in R trying to calculate the area of overlap between polygons. As an example, for Switzerland I have data on the administrative boundaries of the cantons and the [ethnic groups](http://www.icr.ethz.ch/data/other/greg) in the country.

```
## Libraries
library(sp)
library(spdep)
library(maptools)
library(rgeos)

## Data
print(load(url("http://gadm.org/data/rda/CHE_adm1.RData")))
greg<-readShapeSpatial("raw_data/GREG.shp",
                     proj4string=CRS(" +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0")) 
switzerland<-greg[greg$COW==225,]

## Identical projections
proj<-CRS(" +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0")
switzerland<-spTransform(switzerland,proj)
```

Plotting the data and we get something that looks like this:

```
## Plot data
par(mar=c(1,1,1,1))
plot(gadm,col="grey80")
plot(switzerland,add=TRUE,lwd=2,border="red")
```

[image]

We can see that the boundaries for the ethnic groups don't follow the national borders entirely, but good enough. What I am trying to do is for each of the cantons calculate the number of ethnic groups, taking into account the area of the ethnic group within the canton. So for Graubünden in the East I want to know the area occupied by German Swiss, Italian Swiss, Rhaetoromaniens, etc..

Reading some of the similar questions here on stackoverflow I thought that `gIntersection` is the command to use, but this gives me the following error:

```
int<-gIntersection(gadm,switzerland,byid=TRUE) # Updated


Error in RGEOSBinTopoFunc(spgeom1, spgeom2, byid, id, drop_lower_td, "rgeos_intersection") : 
TopologyException: no outgoing dirEdge found at 7.3306802801147688 47.439399101791921
In addition: Warning message:
In RGEOSBinTopoFunc(spgeom1, spgeom2, byid, id, drop_lower_td, "rgeos_intersection") :
spgeom1 and spgeom2 have different proj4 strings
```

Not entirely sure what causes the second warning mission though since

```
identicalCRS(gadm,switzerland)
[1] TRUE
```

Does anyone have a suggestion on how I could calculate the overlap between the cantons and the ethnic groups?

### Update: Possible solution

This might be a possible solution, although the warning on different proj4 strings persists. Also note that there is some measurement error (in Aargua for instance) due to the fact that the ethnic groups shape file does not follow the national borders correctly.

```
## Possible solution
int<-gIntersection(gadm,switzerland,byid=T) # Multiple polygons per province
n<-names(int)
n<-data.frame(t(data.frame(strsplit(n," ",fixed=TRUE)))) 

colnames(n)[1:2]<-c("id0","ethnic.group")
n$area<-sapply(int@polygons, function(x) x@area)
a<-data.frame(id0=row.names(gadm),total.area=gadm$Shape_Area)
df<-merge(n,a,all.x=TRUE)

df$share.area<-df$area/df$total.area*100
```

Comment: I think you need to use the `rgdal` package. Did you check the help page of `spTransform`? It says that `sp` just defines the generic, but to actually change the coordinates you need `rgdal`.

Comment: I did check the `spTransform` help page and think that the syntax I used is correct. With `rgdal` loaded I do get the same error though. Could I be overlooking something here?

Comment: I can't say what generates that error, since I don't have access to the `GREG.*` files. Are they available somewhere?

Comment: Yeah, if you click on the blue link in the text for [ethnic groups](http://www.icr.ethz.ch/data/other/greg) you get to the data webpage where you'll need to download the "GREG shapefile".

Comment: It seems that the error arises when you try to `gIntersects` the whole `gadm` with the whole `switzerland` object. I tried `res<-matrix(FALSE,nrow=nrow(gadm@data),ncol=nrow(switzerland@data)); for (i in 1:nrow(gadm@data)) for (j in 1:nrow(switzerland@data)) res[i,j]<-gIntersects(gadm[i,],switzerland[j,])` and everything works, except for the warning part (which I suspect shouldn't be an issue). The lines above says if the jth ethnic group is present in the ith canton. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Well, partially. What I actually need to know is the actual area, so the jth ethnic group is present in x km² in the ith canton. In the code I actually forgot to include `byid=TRUE`. I updated the code to reflect this. Doing this I get a spatial polygon object which does have the area data I think. Only need to find out how to extract it.

Comment: The `areaPolygon` function of the `geosphere` package gives you the area in km^2. Try for instance: `areaPolygon(int,r=6378.137)`.

Comment: The warning is because the p4s string in one of the shapefiles has a space at the beginning.

Comment: Also, you can answer your own question, so if you're satisfied with your own solution, you should post that as an answer, not in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a method slightly different that yours (but only slightly).

Inspection of `switzerland@data` reveals that, while there are 11 `FeatureIDs` (representing ethnicitity's), there are only 4 unique named ethnicity's (German, Italian, and French Swiss, and Rhaetoromanians). So the result below is based on the names, not the IDs.

```
library(rgeos)    # for gIntersection(...), etc.
library(rgdal)    # for readOGR(...)

setwd("<directory to accept your files>")
CH.1903 <- "+proj=somerc +lat_0=46.95240555555556 +lon_0=7.439583333333333 +k_0=1 +x_0=600000 +y_0=200000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=674.374,15.056,405.346,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs"

print(load(url("http://gadm.org/data/rda/CHE_adm1.RData")))
gadm <- spTransform(gadm, CRS(CH.1903))
download.file("http://www.icr.ethz.ch/data/other/greg/GREG.zip","GREG.zip")
unzip("GREG.zip")
greg <- readOGR(dsn=".",layer="GREG")
greg <- spTransform(greg[greg$COW==225,],CRS(CH.1903))

gadm.ids <- gadm@data$ID_1               # Canton Nr.
greg.ids <- unique(greg@data$G1SHORTNAM) # ethnicity
get.area <- Vectorize(function(adm,reg){
  int <- gIntersection(gadm[gadm$ID_1==adm,],greg[greg$G1SHORTNAM==reg,],byid=TRUE)
  if (length(int)==0) return(0)
  gArea(int)
})
result <- outer(gadm.ids,greg.ids,FUN=get.area)
rownames(result) <- gadm.ids
colnames(result)  <- greg.ids
result <- as.data.frame(result)
totals <- rowSums(result)
result <- result/totals
result$totals <- totals/1e6
result$land.area <- sapply(rownames(result),function(p)gArea(gadm[gadm$ID_1==p,])/1e6)
result
#     German Swiss French Swiss Italian Swiss Rhaetoromanians     totals  land.area
# 531  1.000000000   0.00000000    0.00000000    0.000000e+00 1363.27027 1403.22192
# 532  1.000000000   0.00000000    0.00000000    0.000000e+00  244.32279  244.32279
# 533  1.000000000   0.00000000    0.00000000    0.000000e+00  172.40341  172.40341
# 534  1.000000000   0.00000000    0.00000000    0.000000e+00  522.12943  525.73449
# 535  1.000000000   0.00000000    0.00000000    0.000000e+00   70.03116   84.06481
# 536  0.902128658   0.09787134    0.00000000    0.000000e+00 5927.90740 5927.90847
# 537  0.188415744   0.81158426    0.00000000    0.000000e+00 1654.28729 1654.28729
```

Here we transform both shapefiles to CH.1903 which is a Mercator projection centered on Switzerland with units in meters. Then we identify the Canton Nrs. and the ethnicity's, and use `outer(...)` to cycle through both lists, calculating the area of intersection in sq.km (sq.m/1e6) using `gArea(...)` . The final result has one row per Canton, with the percentage of each ethnicity based on land area. `$totals` is the summation of the intersected areas for each Canton, and `$land.area` is the total geographic land area in the Canton. So this gives you an idea of the error due to incomplete overlaps between the ethnicity shapfile and the gadm shapefile.