# How to spatial join 2 spatial polygon data frames?

Tags: r, r-sp

I'm new in R;) I have 2 SpatialPolygonsDataFrames that I want to spatially join. But I haven't found helpful info so far.

So the 2 SpatialPolygonsDataFrames are exactly alike. Same shapes,extent,crs,number of rows in data frame(numer of shapes). Only they have no common ID to combine the two. So I thought I could do a spatial join, like I used before in ArcGIS?!

So I found some code about merging but that's not what I want and I don't really know how to change it, so it fits my intentions.

As output I want 1 spatial polygon data frame with the attributes(columns) of the 2 input data frames combined. I hope someone can help me!

Comment: maybe you could provide some sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm trying to stick to `sp` and `rgeos`.

If both SpatialPolygonsDataFrames, as I understand, contain the exact same polygons you can do:

```
library(raster)

int <- intersect(sp1, sp2)
```

It creates a new SpatialPolygonsDataFrames with the data columns from both inputs and since the polygons overlap complete you'll get the same polygons.

**UPDATE:** If the polygons aren't exactly the same take the centroid of one SpatialPolygonsDataFrames and merge it with the other.

```
centroids <- gCentroid(sp1, byid = T)
sp1_centroid <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(centroids, sp1@data)

centroiddata <-  sp2 %over% sp1_centroid 

sp12 <- spCbind(sp2, centroiddata)
```

If the polygons have weird shapes but are overall still very similar one could do the same with `gPointsOnSurface()` instead as `gCentroid()` can apparantly calculate centroids outside of the polygon. If the polygons in both df are very dissimilar one probably should calculate the overlap, maybe like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27079422/r-calculating-overlap-polygon-area) and choose the one with the biggest overlap.

Comment: thanks that works, but it seems that there are some miniature differences in the extend and so it creates more polygons than i want to... do you think there is something like "has its center in" instead of intersect? or should i rather first create point from one data frame?!?

Comment: Yes you could create centroids from the polygons in one df and join them with the other df. I'll look into it myself.

Comment: in case you have weird shaped polygons, gCentroid may find a point that is outside of it's according polygon. the better way is to use :                                y <- st_as_sf(dist_sp) # only necessary when you don't already have an sf object     ;   
xs <-st_point_on_surface(y)     ;
points_sp<-as(xs, "Spatial") #to turn it back into spatial point

Comment: Wow, I did not know that. I made a little research and there is a `sp` version of `st_point_on_surface()` called `gPointsOnSurface()`. This way you wouldn't have to convert it back and forth. I'll update my answer. But there still might be wrong matches as a random point in one polygon of df1 may fall into another polygon of df2.